Python: Calling a class method of the superclass explicitly works yet calling it with super() breaks because of optional variables in the superclass
I am trying to call the class method of the superclass (Sample) but when I do I get a type error.  I can fix this by explicitly calling the Sample.from_dict(row) rather than super().from_dict(row).  I just don't understand the difference:
Superclass:
from typing import Optional
from exceptions import InvalidSampleError

class Sample:
    def __init__(
            self,
            sepal_length: float,
            sepal_width: float,
            petal_length: float,
            petal_width: float,
            species: Optional[str] = None,
            classification: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:
        self.sepal_length = sepal_length
        self.sepal_width = sepal_width
        self.petal_length = petal_length
        self.petal_width = petal_width
        self.species: Optional[str] = species
        self.classification: Optional[str] = classification

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, row: dict[str, str]) -> "Sample":
        try:
            return cls(
                sepal_length=float(row["sepal_length"]),
                sepal_width=float(row["sepal_width"]),
                petal_length=float(row["petal_length"]),
                petal_width=float(row["petal_width"]),
            )
        except ValueError as ex:
            raise InvalidSampleError(f"invalid {row!r}")


Subclass:
from sample import Sample
from typing import Optional

class InvalidSampleError(ValueError):
    """Source data file has invalid data representation"""

class Species(Enum):
    Setosa = "Iris-setosa"
    Versicolor = "Iris-versicolor"
    Viginica = "Iris-virginica"

class KnownSample(Sample):
    def __init__(
            self,
            sepal_length: float,
            sepal_width: float,
            petal_length: float,
            petal_width: float,
            species: str,
            classification: Optional[str] = None,
    ) -> None:
        super().__init__(sepal_length, sepal_width, petal_length, petal_width, species, classification)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, row: dict[str, str]) -> "KnownSample":
        # Validate the species
        if row["species"] not in [species.value for species in Species]:
            raise InvalidSampleError(f"invalid species in {row!r}")

        try:
            # Create a Sample instance with the species argument added
            sample = Sample.from_dict(row)

            # Now return a KnownSample using the additional 'species' argument
            return cls(
                sepal_length=sample.sepal_length,
                sepal_width=sample.sepal_width,
                petal_length=sample.petal_length,
                petal_width=sample.petal_width,
                species=row["species"],  # Pass the species from the row to the KnownSample
                classification=sample.classification
            )
        except ValueError as ex:
            raise InvalidSampleError(f"invalid {row!r}")

Usage:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ks = {"sepal_length": 5.1, "sepal_width": 3.5, "petal_length": 1.4, "petal_width": 0.2, "species": "Iris-setosa"}
    us = {"sepal_length": 5.1, "sepal_width": 3.5, "petal_length": 1.4, "petal_width": 0.2}
    known_sample = KnownSample.from_dict(ks)
    unknown_sample = Sample.from_dict(us)
    print(known_sample)
    print(unknown_sample)

This works but when I replace the line:
sample = Sample.from_dict(row)
With:
sample = super().from_dict(row)
I get TypeError: KnownSample.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'species'

super().from_dict(row) doesn't mean "call Sample.from_dict(row)". It means "find the next from_dict implementation (which happens to be the one in Sample), but call it on cls".
You don't want to build an instance of whatever cls happens to be. You want to build an instance of Sample. Sample's from_dict implementation doesn't handle KnownSample properly anyway, due to the constructor signature mismatch. So you should call Sample.from_dict(row), not super().from_dict(row)
